# React Router basename is working only for exact path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react router like this.

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const Base = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router basename="research">
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Base />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And inside my `App` component i have some routes.

```js
<Route path="/" component={SearchPage} />
<Route path="/article/ name="article" component{ArticlePage} />
```

It normally renders first path, but i when i navigate to article's page i can't get the content.

Comment: Yout missing a closing " from this line on path:

Comment: `<Route path="/article/ name="article" component{ArticlePage} />`

Comment: `<Route path="/article/" name="article" component{ArticlePage} />` is what it should look like..

Comment: I have added it, but nothing is going on